# How to add multiple checkboxes over an image

Tags: html, css

I have an image that needs to have around 30 checkboxes over it.
How exactly can I position these checkboxes? I have tried `position:relative` and `position:absolute` but it didn't work. The checkboxes need to be at the exact location of the [image](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/4123/3s9Qi5.png).
In the image I need to add a checkbox over to each tooth.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div style="position:relative; background-image:url('tooth.png'); top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 1280px; width: 912px;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check1" style="position:absolute; bottom: 10px" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is this supposed to look like? Position the checkboxes in what fashion, a grid, at specific places, in a pattern...what?

Comment: Please add more description of what the result should looks like.

Comment: see this image?
http://imageshack.com/a/img538/4123/3s9Qi5.png
i need to add a checkbox over to each tooth.

Comment: Well you could position each checkbox individually but it would be hard to make it responsive. If responsiveness is not required then it would be just a matter of plugging in the numbers. Frankly, though, I'd use an SVG and each tooth could be it's own clickable object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean u need add `display:block` for parent container. Check my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/skriming/euuaa3uf/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes